# How to read the CrackForest Dataset?

Tags: dataset

CrackForest Dataset: https://github.com/cuilimeng/CrackForest-dataset

how to read the groundTruth? *.mat files

Answer (score 0):

import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import cv2

mat = scipy.io.loadmat('001.mat')

np_seg = mat['groundTruth'][0][0][0]

(y, x) = np.where(np_seg == 2)

np_seg[y, x] = 255

(y, x) = np.where(np_seg == 1)

np_seg[y, x] = 0

cv2.imwrite('./001.png', np_seg)

print()